# How can I setup my M-Audio soundcard on Windows for multi-track recording?

Tags: audio-recording, daw, multichannel, m-audio

I'm hoping this is a proper site to post this question on. I will give some context before asking my question.

So this is how my setup looks:

- 32 channel Analog sound board, each channel having a 1/4 in. analog output.
- a [M-Audio](http://www.m-audio.com/) 8 channel FireWire sound card, plugged into a [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) machine.

I've spent hours online trying to figure out how to setup multi-track recording on Windows, and everything I've read has been on stereo recording, but I'm looking to record all eight tracks at once individually.

What should I do to set this up for 8-channel recording? What drivers do I need, what software can I use for recording?

P.S.
Free's always better, for the drivers and the recording software. And as much as I would love to, installing [UbuntuStudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) or [OSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) is not possible.

Comment: Entry level DAWs that can do this, like Ableton Live Lite, are often included for free with things you buy (like a microphone). This is just an example/something to keep an eye out for, but Ableton Live Lite can record 8 tracks at once, and I got it for free that way (and use it with Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to dig into the sound-card settings within whatever program you decide on, specifically you'll need to find the "ASIO" settings.

Unfortunately this differs widely between different software.

I don't recommend Audacity for multi-tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Check out n-Track studio. Prior to switching to OSX & Logic Pro I used n-Track on a windows machine and it worked quite well. Last I saw they had a sub $50 option...good to get your feet wet before jumping into a more $$$ DAW.

If you really need/want free then just google "windows multitrack recording software free", back when I was looking there were also some free options but they didn't measure up to what n-Track provided...perhaps the landscape has changed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that DAW. It is frustrating how bad of a platform Windows is for this kind of thing. I really just need something super basic, just recording and vary basic editing. I was hoping to use audacity but could find no way to record more than stereo without a lot of revisions.

Comment: Windows is an absolutely fine platform for multi-track recording; you're just missing some of the basics.

DAW software will be required on any OS. 

@scott-russell, I don't think this answer actually addresses OP's question, "What should I do to set this up for 8-channel recording?".